# Проблема при переходе на gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Добрый день! 
Имеется следующая структура проекта

```
MainProgect(Он же root всего проекта)

    --SubProgectLib    
        build.gradle

    --SubProgectLib2    
        build.gradle

    --src
    --res

    AndroidManifest.xml
    settings.gradle
    build.gradle
```

В файл  settings.gradle прописано

```
include ':SubProgectLib'
include ':SubProgectLib2'
```

при сихронизации прокта с помощью Gradle выдает

```
Gradle 'MainProgect' project refresh failed:
         Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

**gradle.build**

```
buildscript
        {
            repositories
                    {
                        mavenCentral()
                    }
            dependencies
                    {
                        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
                    }
        }

allprojects
        {
            repositories
                    {
                        mavenCentral()
                    }
        }

apply plugin: 'android'
android
        {
            compileSdkVersion 19
            buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

            defaultConfig
                    {
                        minSdkVersion 8
                        targetSdkVersion 19
                        versionCode 1
                        versionName "1.0"
                    }

            sourceSets
                    {
                        main
                                {
                                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                                }
                    }

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    runProguard false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                }
            }
        }

dependencies
        {

            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'            
            compile project(':SubProgectLib')
            compile project(':SubProgectLib2')
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        }
```

Не могу понять, как исправит. Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался.

**UPD:** в общем проблема была глупой. как оказалось, в одном из SubProgectLib не было gradle.build. Хотя я был уверен в обратном.

Comment: вы можете выложить файл build.gradle полностью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение похожей на вашу проблему: [Android Gradle build with sub projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971375/android-gradle-build-with-sub-projects)

Comment: нет, я видел этот пост. там структура другая